# Why would you use oil on your table tennis raquets?

Tags: equipment, table-tennis, racket

I often see vendors selling oil for table tennis racquets.

Why would one want to use oil on their table tennis racquets?

Comment: can I use Olive oil for table tennis?

Comment: I would never think of oil. How about Mobile 1, the synthetic motel oil for cars?

Comment: Sorry, I mean automotive lubrication oil. Should that be 0 weight or 30 weight? We should try it with an old rubber.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The oil is used to increase the grip or "tackiness" of the rubber surface of the racquet. You can actually just use ordinary oils (like sunflower oil) but the oils vendors sell are manufactured for the specific purpose of applying to table tennis rubber.

Anyway, you want to use a medium width brush (like something you'd use to paint model airplanes or something like that) to apply a coat of the oil evenly on to the rubber, then let it soak into the rubber (can take anywhere from 20 minutes to a few hours depending on the rubber). Then repeat this process (applying the oil and letting it soak in) 2-3 times.

Advanced players need very tacky rubber to impart the type of spin on the ball that they want as well as to deal with the spins put on the ball by their opponents shots. Really tacky rubber on a racquet should allow you to pick a ball up off the table using just the rubber surface.

Comment: You shouldn't use natural oils on sports equipment (or leather etc.), it will rot and degrade the material it was applied to.  Some mineral oils may be OK, though I don't know if they'd work for table tennis racquets.

Comment: I always thought it was some sort of wax and not regular oil...

Comment: How about some EVOO?????@jamauss

Comment: Can I use oil to restore an old and dry rubber to a good state?